# Problems about update, enter, exit data and select in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm doing a visual project to show natural disaster in 1900-2018 using d3. I want add an interactive action that one can choose the first year and last year to show.
Originally I create the picture as the following:

```
d3.csv("output.csv", rowConventer, function (data) {
            dataset = data;
            var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
                .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                .range([padding, width - padding])
                .paddingInner(0.05);
            var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0, 
                    d3.max(dataset, function (d) {
                        return d.AllNaturalDisasters;
                    })])
                .range([height - padding, padding])
                .nice();

            stack = d3.stack().keys(["Drought", "Earthquake", "ExtremeTemperature", "ExtremeWeather", "Flood", "Impact", "Landslide", "MassMovementDry", "VolcanicActivity", "Wildfire"]);
            series = stack(dataset);
            gr = svg.append("g");
            groups = gr.selectAll("g")
            .data(series)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                return colors(i);
            })
            .attr("class", "groups");
            rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
                .data(function(d) { return d; })
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i);
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d[1]);
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1]);
                })
                .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
                .append("title")
                .text(function (d) {
                    var rect = this.parentNode;// the rectangle, parent of the title
                    var g = rect.parentNode;// the g, parent of the rect.
                    return d.data.Year + ", " + d3.select(g).datum().key + "," + (d[1]-d[0]);
                });
           d3.select("button")
               .on("click", choosePeriod);
```

I have simplified some code to make my question simple. At the last row, I add an event listener to achieve what I described above. And the update function is choosePeriod. Now it is as following:

```
    function choosePeriod() {
        firstYear = parseInt(document.getElementById("FirstYear").value);
        lastYear = parseInt(document.getElementById("LastYear").value);
        d3.csv("output.csv", rowConventer, function (newdata) {
            dataset = newdata;
            series=stack(dataset);
            groups.data(series);
            groups.selectAll("rect")
                .data(function (d) {
                    return d;
                })
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScales(i);
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return yScales(d[1]);
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return yScales(d[0]) - yScales(d[1]);
                })
                .attr("width", xScales.bandwidth())
                .append("title")
                .text(function (d) {
                    var rect = this.parentNode;// the rectangle, parent of the title
                    var g = rect.parentNode;// the g, parent of the rect.
                    return d.data.Year + ", " + d3.select(g).datum().key + "," + (d[1]-d[0]);
                });
            groups.selectAll("rect")
                    .data(function (d) {
                        return d;
                    })
                    .exit()
                    .remove();

        })
    }
```

The change of dataset is achieved by `rowConventer`, which is not important in this question. Now the function`choosePeriod` is not running as envisioned! The`enter` and the `exit` and `update` are all not work well! The whole picture is a mess! What I want is, for instance, if I input the `firstYear=1900` and the `lastYear=2000`, then the picture should be updated with the period 1900-2000 to show. How can I achieve it?
I am unfamiliar the arrangement of the entire structure, I mean, at some place using `d3.select()` by `class` or `id` instead of `label` is better, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've dealt with the enter and the exit selections. The only bit you're missing is the update selection, which will deal with the rectangles that already exist and don't need adding or removing. To do this copy your update pattern but just remove the enter().append() bit, e.g.:

```
groups.selectAll("rect")
                .data(function (d) {
                    return d;
                })
                .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScales(i);
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return yScales(d[1]);
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return yScales(d[0]) - yScales(d[1]);
                })
                .attr("width", xScales.bandwidth())
                .append("title")
                .text(function (d) {
                    var rect = this.parentNode;// the rectangle, parent of the title
                    var g = rect.parentNode;// the g, parent of the rect.
                    return d.data.Year + ", " + d3.select(g).datum().key + "," + (d[1]-d[0]);
                })
```

Comment: ummm actually, the enter(), exit(), update() are all not working correctly. And this is what I am puzzled about. Thanks and sorry for forgetting said this first time!

Comment: Wait!! Sorry for not trying your method ten hours ago, I've tried that just now using the `update` `enter` and `exit` sequence and it is running correctly!